# How to filter the props for to render with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code that get data of a `json-server`. And to render seven names in the screen. I want to filter by input and to render only the elements filtereds.

My Apps.js:

```
class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  state = {
employeeCurrent: [],
employee: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
```

.

```
then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));
  }

  add = name => {
this.setState(prevState => {
  const copy = prevState.employeeCurrent.slice();
  copy.push(name);
  return {
    employeeCurrent: copy
  };
});
  };

  render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="router">
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={props => (
          <Home
            {...props}
            add={this.add}
            employee={this.state.employee}
            currentEmployee={this.state.currentEmployee}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/user/:id"
        component={props => (
          <User
            {...props}
            employee={this.state.employee}
            currentEmployee={this.state.currentEmployee}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
  }
}
```

My `body.js` (Where has the function for to render)

```
 class Body extends React.Component {
  getName = () => {
    const { employee, add } = this.props;
    return employee.map(name => (
      <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.name}`}>
        {" "}
        <div onClick={() => add(name)} key={name.id} className="item">
          {" "}
          <img
            className="img"
            src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.name}`}
          />{" "}
          <h1 className="name"> {name.name} </h1>
        </div>{" "}
      </Link>
    ));
      };

      render() {
    return <div className="body">{this.getName()}</div>;
      }
    }
```

I tried to pass the state to the App. JS but had no success. I tried everything in the Body. JS but also not succeeded.  Could someone help me how to do this?

> I'm on the phone so there are some things that are bad to indent. Sorry!

Comment: Where is the filtering happening here?

Comment: so If I am not wrong you want to filter the names according to the input right?

Comment: @AbidHasan this code not be

Comment: @MontyGoldy yes, they are..

Comment: man, you can use "filter" high order function to get the result. For eg:- const filteredNames = this.state.employee.filter(x => x.name === (check with the input value))

Comment: @MontyGoldy some getting props i can to do the filter for to render only the elements filtered...?

Comment: Do you want to render filtered names?

Comment: Yesss, exactly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170189/discussion-between-montygoldy-and-jota).

Comment: right now you are rendering getName() which renders all of the names. So what you can do is before doing the employee.map method you can do the filter first and then do the map on filteredNames

Comment: Ohh, allright brow, i will do this then. Very much thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  getName = () => {
    const { employee, add } = this.props;

    //Filter  names in employee array with input 

    const filterNames = employee.filter(x => x.name === "check with the input value" );

     // Then map over the filtered names

    return filterNames.map(name => (
      <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.name}`}>
        {" "}
        <div onClick={() => add(name)} key={name.id} className="item">
          {" "}
          <img
            className="img"
            src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.name}`}
          />{" "}
          <h1 className="name"> {name.name} </h1>
        </div>{" "}
      </Link>
    ));
      };

      render() {
    return <div className="body">{this.getName()}</div>;
      }
    }
```